# GIN does not provide all of the postgres db values in get request

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a Postgres DB which has the following entry

[image: postgresql db table]

I'm using GIN and have the following in my main function

```golang
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=%s TimeZone=%s", env_var.Host, env_var.User, env_var.Password, env_var.DBname, env_var.Port, env_var.SSLMODE, env_var.TimeZone)
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect to db")
    }

    router.GET("/source/:id", han.GetSource(db))

    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

Here are the structs and handlers

```golang
func GetSource(db *gorm.DB) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        id := c.Param("id")
        var source models.Source
        db.Where("id = ?", id).Find(&source)

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, source)
    }
}

type Source struct {
    ID            int       `json:"id"`
    Source_Name   string    `json:"source_name"`
    Abrviation    string    `json:"abrviation"`
    Last_Modified time.Time `json:"last_modified"`
}

func (Source) TableName() string {
    return "artwork_migrate_source"
}
```

When I use the following curl command

```
curl localhost:8080/source/1
```

I get the following response:

```
{"id":1,"source_name":"Rijksmuseum","abrviation":"","last_modified":"2022-08-05T00:00:00Z"}%
```

So far so good, but if you notice, the "abbreviation" field is empty. The field in my db is of type varchar with a limit of 3.

Comment: Sorry for the improper indentation, you can assume the code is properly indented and not causing syntax errors!

Comment: The screenshot shows `abriviation` whereas your code uses `abrviation` (note the missing `i`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake, I misspelled the "Abriviation" field in the struct.

Thanks to @Brits

Comment: I suspect the word you want is "Abbreviation" (so they were probably both misspelt :-) ) but, given your example mentioned the `Rijksmuseum`, I did not want to assume it was English.